# Macbook pro missing the SSD after upgrading to 1TB

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro early 2013 A1398. I decided to upgrade the SSD from 250GB to [1TB](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0784SY515/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) using an adpater ([M.2 NGFF M Key SSD to A1398](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07Q26MNHC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)).
Everything was working fine and installed Catalina OS and all my apps. It worked great for 2 days without any issues.
On the third day, it stopped booting and a folder with question mark appeared.
I started booting from the USB to access the disk utility and I found that the SSD is missing.

Could someone please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: the photo you posted doesn't tell us anything.  It would be nice to know the size of the drive that it sees (disk0).  Now, if it worked for 2 days, then it's entirely possible that the drive or the adapter failed.  Can you put the old drive back and see if everything is still working?

Comment: ... and before you put the old drive back, wiggle the parts to see if it was simply a case of a loose connection.

Comment: Electronic components more often fail early in their lifecycle, in my experience. Assuming that everything is plugged in firmly and correctly I would say that one of the components has likely failed. Can you put the old SSD back in and confirm the Mac itself is still OK?

Comment: Disk 0 seems a recovery partition its only 2 MB in size, I didn't take the photo for it. However, when I put the old SSD back is working as normal. I guess its either SSD or the adapter has failed. I wonder why!! It was working for 2 days fine. did I miss any configurations? the only configuration I did is the TRIM Support enabled to Yes and resetting the SMC. It didn't show any symptoms like freezing or hanging. Its just when I was trying to turn it on it didn't wake up :( .

Comment: Disk0 **IS** the macOS recovery drive. It is in RAM and allows you to boot and recover the Mac with Time Machine or just an Internet connection, and use Disk Utility to see and operate on connected drives. If it is the read-only Mac OS X Base System (Recovery "Drive)" you can just see it and a few details about it.